# Fulltext search not working with keywords "one"

Tags: mysql

HI I am facing a weird problem in fulltext search.

my query is.

```
SELECT  `itemid`, `title`,  `image`, 
  MATCH( `itemid`, `title`, `product_id`,`p1_name`, `p2_name`) 
  AGAINST ("+samsung +one" IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS score 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE `active_flag`='1' AND `image`!='' 
  AND `new_price`>'0' AND 
  MATCH( `itemid`, `title`, `product_id`,`p1_name`, `p2_name`) AGAINST ( "+samsung +one" IN BOOLEAN MODE ) !=0 
  ORDER BY score DESC;
```

this giving me the data which does not match the word "one" in fulltext indexed fields.
even if i include any of word or all these word like "one two three four" as search param it gives me results.

Comment: Is `one` in 50% of your records included? *Words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match*

Comment: no its not there. 
even if my search keyword is "samsung one two three four five six" it gives results for samsung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql fulltext indexing implements "stopwords" - common words that are ignored for searching purposes, eg "a", "the", etc and even some quite long words like "corresponding".

The default list of stopwords includes the word "one", which is why it isn't getting any matches. See [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) for the full list.

You can control the list by editing this file:

```
myisam/ft_static.c
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, full-text search only matches words of four or more characters.

To match shorter words, you'll need to [change the appropriate parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) (`innodb_ft_min_token_size` or `ft_min_word_len`, depending on the database engine you're using) and rebuild your indexes.